# How to call the same class function in controller

Tags: php, yii

My sample code.. i dont know how to call

```
 class sample
    {
      public function actionExample()
      {
          code here
           // To call php function

      }
      public function a()
     {
        echo "test":
      }

   }
```

Comment: just like in any other PHP Class http://devzone.zend.com/6/

Answer (score 1):

```
class className {

    function mone() {
       // CODE
    } 

    function mTwo() {
       // calling mone in mtwo
       $this->mone();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy

```
class sample
 {
      public function actionExample()
      {
          $this->a(); 

           // To call php function

      }
      public function a()
      {
         echo "test":
      }

  }
```

**Check this for more reference.** 
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6471-call-another-controllers-action/

Answer (score 0):

bu using `$this`
**eg:-**

```
$this->functionName();
```

**$this** acts as an object of the containing controller and using this you can access the variables and functions as well.
**eg:-**

```
public $myvar;
```

You can access it using

```
$this->myvar='value';
```

similarly for functions

```
public function firstfun()
{
//some code
}
```

you can **call it** using

```
$this->firstfun()
```